# How does path method work in akka-http

Tags: scala, akka-http

This is more of a Scala question but inspired by this http-scala example.

```
val route =
      path("hello") {
        get {
          complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
        }
      }
```

Based on example `path` seems like it could be a curried method that takes `String` as first argument and `Route` as second although I do not see such implementation in the API. Could someone enlighten me how this works?

Link to docs: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/javadsl/server/Directives$.html#path(segment:String,inner:java.util.function.Supplier[akka.http.javadsl.server.Route]):akka.http.javadsl.server.Route

Answer (score 2):

No, `path` is not a curried function.  The [API](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/#akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives) gives the signature:

```
def path[L](pm: PathMatcher[L]): Directive[L]
```

Path is a simple unary function that takes in a `PathMatcher` and returns a Directive.  Path only seems like it is a curried function because `Directive` has [an apply method](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/index.html#akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive@apply(v1:T1):R) which makes it appear to be a function, but it's actually a class.

**PathMatcher**

By importing `Directives._` the following implicit function becomes available:

```
implicit def _segmentStringToPathMatcher(segment: String): PathMatcher0
```

Note: `PathMatcher0` is defined as `PathMatcher[Unit]` since it does not pass the matched value along to the inner `Route`.

Calling path with the argument in the example, `path("hello")`, is similar to following code:

```
val directive : Directive[Unit] = path(_segmentStringToPathMatcher("hello"))
```

**Directive**

As stated previously, the `Directive` has an apply method that lazily takes in a Route:

```
def apply(v1 : => Route) : Route
```

So your example code is essentially making the following call:

```
val route = 
  directive.apply(get {
                    complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>"))
                  })
```

**Putting It All Together**

Let's simplify the definition of `Route` and mock some logic to demonstrate what is happening:

```
type SimpleRoute : HttpRequest => RouteResult
```

We can now write a version of path using a higher order function.  Our simpler version takes in a `String` and returns a function instead of a Directive.  It gets a little tricky because the returned function is also higher order:

```
def simplePath(pathStr : String) : SimpleRoute => SimpleRoute = 
  (innerRoute : SimpleRoute) => {

    //this is the returned SimpleRoute
    (request : HttpRequest) => {
      if(request.uri.path.toString equalsIgnoreCase pathStr)
        RouteResult.Complete(innerRoute(request))
      else
        RouteResult.Rejected(Seq.empty[Rejection])
    }

  }
```